# (Markov Chains)Help finding another stationary matrix using the hint provided in the book

Tags: matrices, markov-chains

This is my first post here so I apologize if I format something incorrectly.

So I have a transition matrix P,
$$
        \begin{matrix}
        .7 & 0 & .3 \\
        0 & 1 & 0 \\
        .2 & 0 & .8 \\
        \end{matrix}
$$
and I have two stationary matrices R and S respectively,

$$
        \begin{matrix}
        .4 & 0 & .6 \\       
        \end{matrix}
$$
and
$$
        \begin{matrix}
        0 & 1 & 0 \\
        \end{matrix}
$$

I was able to prove that they are both stationary matrices by showing SP=S and RP=R but the next question asks me to find $\mathbf another$ stationary matrix for P using a provided hint. The hint is 
$$
        \begin{matrix}
  \\T=aR+(1-a)S, \\
 0<a<1
        \end{matrix}
$$

I am unsure how to get a stationary matrix from that. Do I just multiply the R matrix by a and then multiply (1-a)S and then add the two resulting matrices together? If I do that then I end up with 1-a in the matrix and that just confuses me more.
Sorry if this is supposed to be basic stuff, I always struggle with math :/

Comment: Fix a value of $a$. Try $a=0.5$, for example. Do you see why the trick works? $$ (aR + (1-a)S) P = a(RP) + (1-a)SP = (aR + (1-a)S)$$, so $aR + (1-a)S$ is also stationary. By the way, I know almost nothing about Markov  matrices, but this is basic matrix theory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The hint is actually pointing at the new stationary matrix. Just prove it really is stationary by verifying $TP = T $.

Comment: Ok thank you. I tend to always overthink the simplest things.

Comment: @user3516525 happens. Also T is called a convex combination of S and R. (A convex combination is a linear combination with coefficients between 0 and 1 that sum up to 1).

Comment: That makes sense because I just used a=0.5 and ended up with T=0.5R+0.5S.   However, does a convex combination also mean that the matrix is stationary?  I'm wondering if I need to go further and actually multiply out the 0.5R+0.5S with the matrix P in order to fully satisfy this question.

Comment: @user3516525 yes you must. You must multiply $T$ with $P$ to show that a convex combination of $R$ and $S$ is stationary. In particular it works for $a=0.5$. If you do the calculations without substituting for $a $ you get that *any* convex combination of $R $ and $S $ is also stationary